# checkboxe states using local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

ok, I have a form with about 30 different checkboxes their status is stored in local storage  (checked or unchecked) using this code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$(':checkbox').on('change', function () {
localStorage.setItem(this.id, this.checked);
});
$(':checkbox').each(function () {   
var status = localStorage.getItem(this.id) === "true" ? true : false;
$(this).prop("checked", status);
});
});
 //]]></script>
```

My problem is, in the form, I have two checkboxes which are set to checked and disabled (as below),

```
<input type="checkbox" name="opt9" value="Yes" id="2" checked="checked"  disabled="disabled"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="opt8" value="Yes" id="6" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"/>
```

How do I keep these permanently checked in local storage and add them to the code I already have (or a complete new code)

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore setting the value of disabled checkboxes by filtering them out.

`$(':checkbox:not(:disabled)')`

Comment: how do I do this please?